# How do I "add" an integer onto the end of a Java byte array?

Tags: java

Say I have a string

```
String myString = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
```

and I convert it to a byte array

```
byte[] myByteArray = myString.getBytes();
```

then, say I have an int

```
int myInt = 42;
```

and I convert it to a byte

```
byte myByte = (byte) myInt;
```

now, say I would like to add the int to the byte array so that when I print the array, it prints out

```
the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog42
```

I tried this, but it didn't work

```
byte[] newByteArray = new byte[myByteArray.length + 1];
System.arraycopy(myByteArray, 0, newByteArray, 0, myByteArray.length);
newByteArray[newByteArray.length-1] = myByte;
String finalString = new String(newByteArray);
System.out.println(finalString);
```

All that gets printed out is

```
the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog*
```

'*' being the ASCII character 42.

So, what is the simplest way to do this?

**EDIT:**

Yes, I know I can append the String "42" to my other string, but I want the integer value stored in the byte array. I was under the assumption that a byte was a byte, and it did not matter if it was a String or an int, because bytes were 1s and 0s under the hood.

Comment: Do you want "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog42" to be the output?

Comment: You're not going to append the `int` for 42, you need to append the bytes corresponding to the appropriate encoding of the characters 4 and 2.

Comment: @resueman yes, I would like that exactly.

Comment: Each byte represents a char in the String, why should it read your int differently?  You'll need to customize a parsing method to convert your mangled byte array back into the String you wish for it to be.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
String myString = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
int myInt = 42;
String temp = myString + String.valueOf(myInt);
byte[] myByteArray = temp.getBytes();
```

Comment: or even shorter: `byte[] myByteArray = (myString + myInt).getBytes();`

Comment: Yes, that would work, but I would like to store the integer, itself, in the byte array.

Comment: Ints are not strings in bytes... "42" vs int 42 are two different bytes, you didn't solve anything

Comment: @Brian the problem you face is that each digit of the `int` is a separate `byte`. First you would need to check the length of the `int`, then create your `byte[]` of appropriate size and THEN get the digits of the `int` one by one and properly convert them into their ASCII values and append them.

Comment: @Brian  if you want to store the number in the byte array, when doing the output, the program have no way to distinguish which byte is for number, which byte is for ASCII character.

Comment: Don't use `getBytes()`, it should be deprecated. Use [`getBytes(Charset)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes-java.nio.charset.Charset-).

Comment: @David, looks like getBytes() is not deprecated. It just use the default charset.  getBytes(int srcBegin, int srcEnd, byte[] dst, int dstBegin) is depreciated.

Comment: Yes, I said it *should* be deprecated. Only call it if it doesn't matter to you if the byte array is in GB2312, ISO-2022-JP, or CP-1098 (Farsi) encoding, or you've taken steps to explicitly set the platform encoding for your JVM.

Comment: @DavidConrad  In some situation, the programmer shall play with the default charset, in this case, getBytes() has its value. For example, if one wants to store a string in a binary file with the default charset.

Comment: @GordonLiang Sure, and then read it back in later, only the default charset has changed (because you updated, or you're reading the file on another system), so you get garbage. It's a bad idea. It causes bugs.

Comment: @DavidConrad  I understand what you mean. Forcing a developer to choose a charset in programming, can eliminate the problem. So that the developer shall create a mechanism to define the charset throughout the program, or let the user select a charset throughout the program.

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer, so as to bypass charset encoding, and assuming it is required to get the characters:

```
            String numString = String.valueOf (newInt);
            String newString  = myString + newInt;
            int newLength = myString.length() + numString.length();
            char[] newCharArray = new char[newLength];

            newString.getChars(0, newLength, newCharArray, 0);
```

With David's comment:

```
     String newString  = myString + newInt;
     char[] newCharArray = newString.toCharArray();
```

Comment: You basically copied @Andics 's answer. Is is not necessary to have the same answer more than once.

Comment: I am not copying, I just post the answer and after that see another answer ahead of me. ; (

Comment: Only use `getBytes()` if you're equally happy with KOI8-R, Shift-JIS, EBCDIC, or CP-868 (Urdu).

Comment: @DavidConrad  yes, I found out that. If he only wants to get each character, possiblly using getChars  is better.  getChars simply copies the characters out.

Comment: There is no `getChars()`? Do you mean `chars()`, or `toCharArray()`?

Comment: @DavidConrad  I mean getChars(int srcBegin, int srcEnd, char dst[], int dstBegin).   This API looks ugly, but it does not need charset encoding, as we are returning the characters...

Comment: Might just as well use `toCharArray()`, then, it does the same thing with less typing.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to just append the int to the end of the string:

```
myString = myString + myInt;
```

Otherwise, you'll need to append the bytes for the characters `'4'` and `'2'` to an expanded byte array, as Sotirios Delimanolis suggested.

I would like to add that using `myString.getBytes()` is a very bad idea. The `getBytes()` method uses the default platform encoding which can differ from system to system, JVM to JVM, or even run to run. You should always prefer the version that takes a `Charset` as a parameter so that you *know* what you're getting, e.g.:

```
myString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Or as I like to say, *Always assume the default platform encoding is EBCDIC and act accordingly.*